# Django queryset pop

Tags: django, django-queryset

Hi I want to do this in my views:

```
recent_articles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
headline_article = recent_articles_list.pop()[0]
```

however, just get the error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

I have also transformed it to a list:

```
headline_article = list(recent_articles_list).pop[0]
```

But then I get:

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: hmmm...why is this down-voted? Seemed like a valid question to me.

Comment: The reason you are getting `builtin_function_or_method object is not subscriptable` is because you're trying to select element [0] of .pop - if you changed it to `.pop()[0]` you wouldn't get that error. And, Django QuerySets don't allow you to pop. You could just do: `headline_article = recent_articles_list[0]` and `other_articles = recent_articles_list[1:]` - although the template method below is better :)

Comment: yes. The template method worked for me, though good to know some of the things you can and can't do to querysets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use it in template, i suggest to use `{{forloop.first}}`

Pass the `recent_articles_list` QuerySet to the template, and:

```
{% for article in recent_articles_list %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <!-- headline article -->
        {{article}}
    {% else %}
        <!-- other articles --->
        {{article}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
headline_article = list(recent_articles_list).pop()
```

Comment: yaa try it and for some of your bigger lists run out of memory

Comment: It's not saving the variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the queryset to a variable:

   ```
   recent_articles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
   ```

---

2. Make the queryset variable a list:

   ```
   headline_article = list(recent_articles_list)
   ```

---

3. Pop the list, and add the popped value to a variable

   ```
   popIndexZeroValue = headline_article.pop(0)
   ```